# Cant Change Cursor Style in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, coding-style, cursor

This feels slightly ridiculous asking this here, but I'm writing a WinForms app and must have accidentally changed the cursor style from "default" to "WaitCursor" but now cant change it back.  Every time I use the drop down to select a different style it just snaps back to the "WaitCursor" option.

The control isn't locked, and im rather confused.

Any help welcome!

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the UseWaitCursor property back to False.

Answer (score -1):

use the insert key on your keyboard ...it will change your cursor style..... more info on this [link](http://webloggerz.com/how-to-change-cursor-from-block-to-regular-in-visual-studio/) over cursors

Comment: I think the OP asked how to change the cursor that is programmatically set within his/her Windows Forms application. Your link discusses changing the cursor while working in VS.